# How disable a <h:selectBooleanCheckbox> pressing a <a4j:commandButton> in jsf

Tags: javascript, jsf, richfaces, ajax4jsf

```
<a4j:form id="formNC">
    <rich:panel style="width: 100%">       
       <h:selectBooleanCheckbox value="#{crearCitaMB.booleanCheck">
       <a4j:commandButton value="DisableCheck" action="#{testBean.methodCalculate}" />
    </rich:panel>
</a4j:form>
```

my question is simple:  can I "disable" not "hide" selectBooleanCheckbox when I press commandButton ... I do not know how make this yet. Can this be done with aj4:support or javascript?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this...

in page:

```
<a4j:form id="formNC">
    <rich:panel style="width: 100%">
       <h:selectBooleanCheckbox disabled="#{testBean.disableFlag"} 
            value="#{crearCitaMB.booleanCheck"}>
       <a4j:commandButton value="DisableCheck" 
            action="#{testBean.methodCalculate}" render="formNC" />
    </rich:panel>
</a4j:form>
```

in testBean:

```
private boolean disableFlag;

public boolean isDisableFlag()
{
    return disableFlag;
}

public void methodCalculate()
{
    disableFlag = true;
    ...
}
```